# Good books for learning C++ programming on UNIX (pref Linux)?

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix

Could users please help me with books that are good for writing C/C++ code on the Unix platform?

My emphasis is on writing low latency code, for use in electronic trading platforms.

(I realise there are a few threads on StackOverflow asking about books for languages generally, but my Q is specifically towards coding on the Unix OS)

Comment: Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books)

Comment: Already covered in the C++ tag wiki. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)
- [W. Richard Stevens - Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment](http://www.kohala.com/start/apue.html)
- [W. Richard Stevens - UNIX Network Programming, Volume 2, Second Edition: Interprocess Communications](http://www.kohala.com/start/unpv22e/unpv22e.html)
- [W. Richard Stevens - UNIX Network Programming](http://www.kohala.com/start/unp.html)

For low latency you really have to dig into some blogs and the source of some cool open-source projects, AFAIK there aren't any books available..

Comment: Edition 1 of 'Stevens' is a tad out of date, particularly for Linux

Comment: Yepp, sorry I should have provided the link for the updated verisons...

Answer (score 3):

Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment (2nd edition) by W.Richard Stevens and Stephen A.Rago, Addison-Wesley.

`man 3 intro`

Answer (score 1):

I think probably for low-level c code on unix/linux, the gold-standard might be Steven's "Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment". Low-latency means you want to code down to the metal, so that's about as low-level as you can get.

There is also nothing like Stroustrup's C++ (now in it's 3rd edition) which also emphasizes clean, tight code, but with some of the benefits of C++. But for low-latency work, you'll just use things like const and references and encapsulation, but maybe forgo some of the more high-level features like inheritance or exceptions.

Comment: Stroustrup's C++ (now in it's **4th** edition)