# System Programming using C++

Tags: c++, system

I want to learn system programming in C++ but I don't know how should start? which topics should I start to learn?
It is important for me to know the topics in both MS-Windows and *NIX operating systems.

(SO sorry for my bad English grammar)

Comment: http://wiki.osdev.org is a good start.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[System programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_programming)** is a very abstract distinction. It is as if you said *graphics programming* or *network programming*.

I **suggest** you pick a specific sub-topic (like system-calls, gpu-interaction, compilier-writing) and explore that.

Answer (score -1):

For a newer, start coding with standard c++, which windows and linux both supports. If you are  interested in system programming, I think Linux best fits you.

Comment: TNX, So whats the best book for this?

Comment: this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342376/good-books-for-learning-c-programming-on-unix-pref-linux may help you.

Answer (score -2):

If you wanna develop in Windows , start with Porgramming Wdinwos.